# RangeError not in inclusive range error 0..9:10, I need the variable TUindex to accept values greater than 9

Tags: flutter, dart

```
//the variables

int CurrentTU = 1;
List TU = <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

//This is the builder

ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: TU.length,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return TUEntry(TUindex:TU[index],
    );},),),
```

// The method it goes to

```
class TUEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  const TUEntry({super.key, required this.TUindex});

  final int TUvalue = 10;
  final int TUindex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: 40,
      width: 40,
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Column (children: [
        if (Events1.elementAt(TUindex) == 'N')
          const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.grey,)
        else
          FIcon(ftr: Events1.elementAt(TUindex)),
        //
        if (Events2.elementAt(TUindex) == 'N')
          const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.grey,)
        else
          FIcon(ftr: Events2.elementAt(TUindex)),
        //
        if (Events3.elementAt(TUindex) == 'N')
          const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.grey,)
        else
          FIcon(ftr: Events3.elementAt(TUindex)),
        //
        if (TUindex == CurrentTU)
          const Icon(Icons.gps_fixed)
        else
          const Icon(Icons.gps_not_fixed),
        //
        if (TUindex == CurrentTU)
          const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward_rounded)
        else
          Container(child: Text('-- $TUindex --'),),
      ],)
   );}
}
```

I've tried using doubles and Strings for the list but nothing changes, still the same error. For some reason I can't set TUindex to be a number outside of 0-9.

I have a itemCount = List.length as I've seen others suggest on other posts.

Comment: `TUindex` can have any value from 1..15 inclusive (it is a value from the `TU` list).  `TUindex` is used to index into the `Events1`, `Events2`, and `Events3` lists, but we don't know what they are.  At least one of them has only 10 elements and therefore cannot be indexed with a value greater than 9.  Nobody can help you further without more details.

Comment: I thought I had isolated that part of the code when I was trying to fix it but apparently not. Thank you sir.